# How can I save and get documents in a nested collection? (waiting on transactions)

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

**edit**: Today I found the time to realize the solution .. I was actually getting the data just fine, but I was throwing it away.  This was a fairly silly async error that I *never* would have had in javascript. All these calls happen at once, but return asynchronously. To keep the data, I'm using this form now (there's probably a better one? but I'm pretty sure I can't avoid making multiple Firebase calls here so the most beautiful solution isnt available):

```
    var newAppsData:[(String, [AppData])] = []

    var tx = 0
    apps.forEach { app in
        tx = tx + 1

        let URI = "\(DataModel.constants.URIappCollection)/\(app)/tx"
        DBIFirebase.db.collection(URI).getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in
//...
            tx = tx - 1
            if tx == 0 {
                if newAppsData.count == 0 { /* keep the data! */
```

### Original

I'm saving time-series data in a collection under each "app" that is using it, with documents labelled by timestamp:

```
let docRef = DBIFirebase.db.document("\(DataModel.constants.URIappCollection)/\(app)/tx/\(dateString)")
            docRef.setData(saveable) { (error) in
```

The result looks right, in the firestore database browser right now I see `sampleData/appName/tx/dateString`s.
[image: screenshot]

So I was thinking I should retrieve them in an analogous fashion:

```
    apps.forEach { app in
        let URI = "\(DataModel.constants.URIappCollection)/\(app)/tx"
        DBIFirebase.db.collection(URI).getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Firestore error loading data for app \(app) - \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            var appData: [AppData] = []

            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
                print("no documents for app \(app)")
                return
            }

            for document in documents {
                let data = document.data()
                //...
    }

    if appsData.count == 0 { // it always is, we do reach this
```

I am surprised to find the `if let error = error` is never reached in the debugger (but the line immediately before it is). Nothing comes up in the console as getDocuments completes .. no firebase or any other errors at all.

In fact, the Usage log shows read operations have occurred today. I'm just not seeing the results..

What could be the problem?

### edits

1. `.getDocuments { (snapshot, error)`turns out to be wrong, changed to `.getDocuments() { (snapshot, error)` -- I was really hopeful but, the result is not different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I found the time to realize the solution .. I was actually getting the data just fine, but I was throwing it away. All these calls happen at once, but return asynchronously. To keep the data, I'm using this form now (there's probably a better one? but I'm pretty sure I can't avoid making multiple Firebase calls here so the most beautiful solution isnt available):

```
    var newAppsData:[(String, [AppData])] = []

    var tx = 0
    apps.forEach { app in
        tx = tx + 1

        let URI = "\(DataModel.constants.URIappCollection)/\(app)/tx"
        DBIFirebase.db.collection(URI).getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in
//...
            tx = tx - 1
            if tx == 0 {
                if newAppsData.count == 0 { /* keep the data! */
```